# How to pass String value in onClick from xml view to java code, except using Tag?

Tags: android

I want to pass String value in onclick method from xml view to java code, except using tags.

I know the tag value is the way to get string value from xml, but i need to pass value as argument of onClick method.

Comment: what kind of view and what string value?

Comment: Relative layout, string value any text

Comment: RelativeLayout don't have property text, why you don't want to use tag?

Comment: can you share you RelativeLayout view and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

`onClick(View v)` receives the clicked `View` as an argument, then you can get the `String` using `v.getTag()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain both the **tag** and **text** on your view (which is most likely a Button).
As long as the view has text, you can get the text.
You can do the following :

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // get the tag
        String tag = v.getTag();
        // if the view is a TextView and you wish to obtain the code from it
        String text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
    }
};
```

Comment: but my view is Relative layout, so i need another option except of tag and text.

Comment: So. 1) you have a relative layout, 2) that relative layout has a tag 3) you want to get the tag from the relative layout when you click on that relativelayout, correct? If not, post a comment with your relative layout code and ill help you with it

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

There is term contentDescription in xml, which we can set our string value in xml and get it in our class, where we declare our onClick method by use ::

view.getContentDescription();